# dynamodb UpdateItem using API Gateway as Proxy, error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am using the AWS API Gateway as proxy to expose DynamoDB API. the UpdateItem mapping is not working, it return:

```
{
  "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
}
```

Below is the mapping template and the payload:

```
{
    "TableName": "registros",
    "Key": {
        "Pk": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.Pk')"
        },
        "Sk": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.Sk')"
            }
    },
    "UpdateExpression": "set intenciones = :intenciones",
    "ConditionExpression": "Pk = :Pk, Sk = :Sk,",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":Pk": {"S": "$input.path('$.Pk')"},
        ":Sk": {"S": "$input.path('$.Sk')"},
        ":intenciones": {"S": "$input.path('$.intenciones')"},
    },
"ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
}
```

Payload:

```
{ 
"Pk":"DemandaProd",
"Sk":"raerytre#22",
"intenciones":"news"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `ConditionExpression` since it's implied with `Key` that you'll be matching on the `Pk` and `Sk`. Try this:

```
{
  "TableName": "registros",
  "Key": {
    "Pk": {
      "S": "$input.path('$.Pk')"
    },
    "Sk": {
      "S": "$input.path('$.Sk')"
    }
  },
  "UpdateExpression": "set intenciones = :intenciones",
  "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
    ":intenciones": { "S": "$input.path('$.intenciones')" }
  },
  "ReturnValues": "UPDATED_NEW"
}
```